# ld could not find .so even with LD_LIBRARY_PATH AND LD_RUN_PATH set

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, intel, ld, mxnet

When I compile mxnet, it said

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -liomp5
```

Then I try

```
ld -liomp5 
ld: cannot find -liomp5
```

but ld -Lpathlibiomp5 -liomp5 said "`ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; not setting start address"`

I have set the following environment variable, but they are not working at all ? Anyone knows why ?

echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
    /home/hpc/pr74ze/ru37wof2/local_software/mxnet/mklml_lnx_2017.0.2.20170209/lib:/lrz/sys/intel/studio2017_u2/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin:/home/hpc/pr74ze/ru37wof2/local_software/mx
net/mklml_lnx_2017.0.2.20170209/lib:/lrz/sys/intel/studio2017_u2/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin:/home/hpc/pr74ze/ru37wof2/local_software/mxnet/mklml_lnx_2017.0.2.20170209/lib:/lrz/sy
s/intel/studio2017_u2/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin:/home/hpc/pr74ze/ru37wof2/local_software/mxnet/mklml_lnx_2017.0.2.20170209/lib:/lrz/sys/intel/studio2017_u2/compilers_and_librari
es_2017.2.174/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin
```

echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
    /lrz/sys/compilers/gcc/6.3/lib64:/lrz/sys/compilers/gcc/6.3/lib:/home/hpc/pr74ze/ru37wof2/local_software/mxnet/mklml_lnx_2017.0.2.20170209/lib:/lrz/sys/intel/studio2017_u2/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux
/mkl/lib/mic:/lrz/sys/intel/studio2017_u2/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux/mkl/lib/intel64:/usr/lib64:/lrz/mnt/sys.x86_64/compilers/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/amd64/server:/home/hpc/pr74ze/ru37wof2/local_so
ftware/mxnet/mklml_lnx_2017.0.2.20170209/lib:/lrz/sys/intel/studio2017_u2/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux/mkl/lib/mic:/lrz/sys/intel/studio2017_u2/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux/mkl/lib/intel64
:/usr/lib64:/lrz/mnt/sys.x86_64/compilers/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/amd64/server:/home/hpc/pr74ze/ru37wof2/local_software/mxnet/mklml_lnx_2017.0.2.20170209/lib:/lrz/sys/intel/studio2017_u2/compilers_and_libraries_
2017.2.174/linux/mkl/lib/mic:/lrz/sys/intel/studio2017_u2/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux/mkl/lib/intel64:/usr/lib64:/lrz/mnt/sys.x86_64/compilers/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/amd64/server:/home/hpc/pr74ze/r
u37wof2/local_software/mxnet/mklml_lnx_2017.0.2.20170209/lib:/lrz/sys/intel/studio2017_u2/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux/mkl/lib/mic:/lrz/sys/intel/studio2017_u2/compilers_and_libraries_2017.2.174/linux
/mkl/lib/intel64:/usr/lib64:/lrz/mnt/sys.x86_64/compilers/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib64:/lrz/mnt/sys.x86_64/compilers/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/lib/amd64/server:/lrz/sys/applications/R/3.2_shared_MK
L/lib/R/lib:/lrz/sys/intel/impi/5.1.3.181/lib64:/lrz/sys/intel/studio2016_u4/debugger_2016/libipt/intel64/lib:/lrz/sys/intel/studio2016_u4/compilers_and_libraries_2016.4.258/linux/compiler/lib/intel64:/home/hpc/p
r74ze/ru37wof2/programs/libevent/lib:/home/hpc/pr74ze/ru37wof2/programs/libevent/lib$:/home/hpc/pr74ze/ru37wof2/programs/libevent/lib$:/home/hpc/pr74ze/ru37wof2/programs/libevent/lib$:/home/hpc/pr74ze/ru37wof2/pr
ograms/libevent/lib
```

How can I solve this compilation problem ?

Comment: Those environment variables control `ld.so` (the dynamic loader), not `ld` (the linker).

Comment: And your try with `-L` *worked*, the missing `_start` is a separate problem, caused by linking only the library and forgetting your program code.

Comment: but the compilation for mxnet(a library) failed due to ld could not find, any solutions?

Comment: It might help to add that `-L` option (including the path to libiomp5.a) into the Makefile of mxnet